# In what ways can we display a progress bar in an android application

Tags: android

In what ways can we display a progress bar in an android application.

ProgressDialog, ProgressBar, requestWindowFeature, ProgressView, and ProgressItem

Answer (score 3):

```
<ProgressBar 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progress" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: i'm asking about the different ways within the java program, not in the xml file.